# What should be used to receive emails in my system using Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am currently working in a project where i am asked to add a feature which receives emails that our clients sends us, after that the email will be saved to our database. I have searched online thoroughly but cant seem to find anything worthy. 
I will be using Asp.net MVC5. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you asking for people to code for you? What have you tried? Show us your code and you might get some help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an open source solution, there is OpenPop.NET http://hpop.sourceforge.net/. If you want a commercial solution, there is Chilkat https://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-features.asp.

These tools are only part of the solution (accessing the email). You also need to determine how the website will know when to go access the email. Will this be a user driven action or something that you need to do automatically?

Answer (score -1):

You can use MailGun API to receive emails:

[here](http://martinnormark.com/how-to-receive-e-mails-in-asp-net-mvc-using-mailgun/)